# Error: No module named pyobjus

Tags: kivy

I installed package kivy-ios. But when I used  *from pyobjus import auto class* , logging command showed :  *no module named pyobjus*. Vist:  https://pyobjus.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Did you run this on an ios device? If not, you need to install pyobjus itself, though note that you can't do anything with the ios api on the desktop (obviously) so you don't need to install it locally if you just want to use it on an ios device.